# How to create a type parametric abstract type in F#?

Tags: generics, types, f#

I would like to create an abstract type the following way:

```
type IResource =
    abstract member List    : string -> List<'T>
```

When I implement it I need a concrete type instead of 'T (for example int).

```
type Website(stage: string) =
    member this.List    stage = (this :> IResource).List    stage
    interface IResource with
      member this.List    stage = []
```

Is it possible to have that in F#? If I give a type to List in the implementation the type checker complains that I use int instead of 'T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your interface explicitly generic by providing type parameter for inteface type:

```
type IResource<'T> =
    abstract member List : string -> List<'T>
```

And then you can specify type when implementing the interface

```
type Website(stage: string) =
    member this.List stage = (this :> IResource<int>).List    stage
    interface IResource<int> with
      member this.List stage = []
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey! Much appreciated.